# Continue div element past horizontal overflow

Tags: html, css

A JSFiddle of it: http://jsfiddle.net/24tL8mkq/3/

I want the red highlighting to continue all the way across the box.

Right now, it's set-up such that:

```
<div style='width: 500px; overflow: auto; border: 1px solid black; padding-top:-5px;'>
    <pre id='pre_1'>
        <!-- code box -->
    </pre>
</div>
```

with the relevant css (this is the CSS that I want to extend across the entire div, through the overflow) being:

```
.bad {
    background-color: palevioletred;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I get that I can't use `width: 100%` as that'll only extend to the right most side of the overflow always, but I can't set a static width as I don't know what the size of the box could be.

I'd really prefer to keep this a HTML/CSS solution if possible just to make this as portable as possible.

Comment: Are you trying to get the red bar to overflow the parent, or are you trying to have the parent be 100% for example?

Comment: I'm trying to get the red bar to overflow so that if I scroll right to view a longer line, it continues. Right now, it ends right on the overflow, so it looks weird when I scroll right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting problem. The following works for me in the latest Firefox, Chrome and IE11, though I'd consider this somewhat "experimental" - definitely should be further tested if you need to support a broader range of browsers.

http://jsfiddle.net/24tL8mkq/5/

```
pre {
    display: table;
}

pre > div { display: flex; }
```

I wish I could tell you why this works, but I don't know. I wasn't able to find another combination that works, however. My guess: setting the `pre` to `display: table` makes it so the width will go wider than 100% (500px), as tables will do (when their children are wider than the table). Setting `flex` on the `div` children is filling the available space since all the children should be equal width.